# pushing in a non-bare repo - two repos in my local, Git

Tags: git, repository, git-push

I have two repo on my local machine, say `local1` and `local2`. So I ran from `local1`

```
git push local2 sombranch
```

and I got this

```
remote: error: refusing to update checked out branch: refs/heads/5-0-stable
remote: error: By default, updating the current branch in a non-bare repository
remote: error: is denied, because it will make the index and work tree inconsistent
remote: error: with what you pushed, and will require 'git reset --hard' to match
remote: error: the work tree to HEAD.
remote: error: 
remote: error: You can set 'receive.denyCurrentBranch' configuration variable to
remote: error: 'ignore' or 'warn' in the remote repository to allow pushing into
remote: error: its current branch; however, this is not recommended unless you
remote: error: arranged to update its work tree to match what you pushed in some
remote: error: other way.
```

The two repos have almost exactly the same histories and the sllight differences could not go into conflicts. Am I forced to change the `receive.denyCurrentBranch` ? I don't really want to turn the remote repo to a bare repo by this command `git config --bool core.bare true`

Answer (score 1):

You have several choices, if you don't want to make local2 a bare repo:

1) Set `receive.denyCurrentBranch`.  But I think the git error message explains pretty clearly how this can cause issues later, so perhaps it's best avoided.

2) Check out a different branch in local2, then do your push from local1.  The error only happens when you attempt to push to the branch that is checked out in the remote repository, so you can avoid it by having a different branch checked out there (which also eliminates the issues with working tree / HEAD synchronization described in the error.)

3) Perhaps the most straightforward, from local2, just do this:

```
git pull local1
```

Since `git pull` updates all three of HEAD, the index, and the working tree, there is no synchronization issue like there is with `git push`, which alters only HEAD.

Comment: Thank for 1) I don't want to do that. But could you explain why is this happening that when you git pull there is no pb ? btw, could you explain plz more in depth 2) (I understand the command but not the underlying thinking)